Can we remove all the pills from a packet while preserving at least one symmetry at each step?
I have some pills in a $4 \times 3$ blister pack, organised into a grid. The pack is symmetric: you could rotate it $\pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2$ about the centre, or reflect it over each of the midlines. If I remove a pill from the middle row, it's still symmetric: you can reflect it over the midline which runs along the middle row, but the other symmetries are gone. Can I remove the pills one by one, always having a symmetry?
For a $4 \times 3$ pack, the answer turns out to be no: at some point I have to remove a corner pill for the first time, after which I have no symmetries, but I do have at least 3 pills left.
For square packs, this argument doesn't work: you have a diagonal line of symmetry between each opposite pair of corners. Indeed, for a $2 \times 2$ pack, any order of removing the pills works.
So, my question is: For which $(n, m)$ can we remove the pills in an $n \times m$ pack such that we have a symmetry at each step?

For $m \neq n$, you can apply the same "ome point I have to remove a corner pill for the first time, after which I have no symmetries" to show that it's not possible. $\quad$ It is doable for $ 3 \times 3$, and I believe it's not doable for any higher $n$. One way to approach it is to take the graph theoretic interpretation where edges are cells that are symmetric, and perhaps see where that leads.

For larger squares, taking any pill that is not on a line of mirror symmetry will immediately break both reflective and rotational symmetries, so 4x4 and larger squares fail when taking for example a pill adjacent to a corner pill.

With a $4\times 3$ pack, you can rotate it by $\pi$ (a half-circle) but not by $\frac\pi2$ (a right angle)

Thank you both. So to summarize the comments, it is possible for squares where $n \leq 3$, or whenever $n$ or $m$ are 1.
